# Full Screen bug with my C# application

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, fullscreen

I'm experiencing a bug with the full screen mode of my C# application. There is no problem when I click the full screen button to go in and out of full screen mode. Same when I use F11, but when I press the full screen button to go into full screen mode and press F11 to go out of it, it goes out of full screen mode for a millisecond or so and goes back to full screen mode immediately. Anyone knows a solution? I use Visual Studio 2012 Express.

I use the fallowing code for my full screen button: (named b8)

```
if (FormBorderStyle != FormBorderStyle.None)
        {
            FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            p1.BackColor = Color.White;
            p2.BackColor = Color.White;
            TopMost = true;
            b8.Image = null;
            b8.Text = "-";
            W.Select();
        }
        else
        {
            FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.Sizable;
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Build >= 7000)
            {
                if (DWM.DwmIsCompositionEnabled())
                {
                    Color c = Color.FromArgb(255, 221, 220, 220);
                    TransparencyKey = c;
                    p1.BackColor = c;
                    p2.BackColor = c;
                    MARGINS mr = new MARGINS();
                    mr.T = 1800;
                    IntPtr h = Handle;
                    int result = DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(h, ref mr);
                }
            }
            TopMost = false;
            b8.Text = null;
            b8.Image = MyApp.Properties.Resources.p;
            W.Select();
        }
```

And this one for F11:

```
if (y==(Keys.F11))
        {
            if (FormBorderStyle != FormBorderStyle.None)
            {
                FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
                WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
                WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
                p1.BackColor = Color.White;
                p2.BackColor = Color.White;
                TopMost = true;
                b8.Image = null;
                b8.Text = "-";
            }
            else
            {
                FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.Sizable;
                WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
                if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Build >= 7000)
                {
                    if (DWM.DwmIsCompositionEnabled())
                    {
                        Color c = Color.FromArgb(255, 221, 220, 220);
                        TransparencyKey = c;
                        p1.BackColor = c;
                        p2.BackColor = c;
                        MARGINS mr = new MARGINS();
                        mr.T = 1800;
                        IntPtr h = Handle;
                        int result = DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(h, ref mr);
                    }
                }
                TopMost = false;
                b8.Text = null;
                b8.Image = MyApp.Properties.Resources.p;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both cases you are calling

```
WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

and that is why your window always goes to full screen. In your second code block, you should remove that call and just leave it to

```
WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't fix the actual problem.

Comment: @CCCP, there are two placed in your second routine the call `FormWindowState.Maximized`. You should remove both.

Comment: I did, it still doesn't fix the actual problem.